# Anyone know what emerged from these cocoons?

Tags: species-identification, species

Found a little universe in the back of a ceramic decoration I put up outside in summer...the concave back was full of grainy soil and several exited cucoons...anyone know what critter this is/was?[image]!

Comment: Could you please add the size of these cocoons and your geographical location?